# Shopify app (rails) has 3 / in the https section for auth redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify-app

I have a simple rails app created from the shopify cli.

I have edite both the dashboard (to be `https://shopify.myapp.com`) and the variables in `config.root_url` to be `config.root_url=shopify.myapp.com/api`.

However, when I run the app (deployed to the url `shopify.myapp.com` hosted on DO) the Auth redirect has `https:///shopify.myapp.com/api/auth/callback`. Notice the three (3) `/` after https.

I can not find any config, setting, or anything that would yield this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was missing the `HOST` environment variable, which is basically undocumented.

(I had hard coded the urls in another file).